# How can i get catecory name and link inside the products list in Prestashop 1.7 using smarty code?

Tags: smarty, prestashop-1.7

I am building a new theme and i am looking for a way to display the category name and the category link inside each product item in product lists. I am using the smarty code

```
{$product.category_name}
```

so i can get the category name of the product that belongs to that category but i really can't find a way (using smarty code) so i can get the url that links to that category. I already tried:

```
<a href="{$product.category_name}">{$product.category_name}</a>
```

but this code generate the url:

```
http://mysite/home-accessories
```

instead of:

```
  Quote

http://mysite/8-home-accessories
```

Does anyone knows how can i make it work using only smarty code ?

Comment: This should do the work: `{$product.id}-$product.category_name}`

Comment: @Crezzur i don't think so. The product_id and category_id are different. Maybe OP can use the category_id, but is not dynamic. Maybe calling getCategoryLink in classes/Link.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{$product.id}-$product.category_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

In prestashop 1.7, the is a smarty utility called url that acts as the prestashop 1.7 equivalent of the prestashop 1.6 $link object. The use is as follows:

Prestashop 1.6 : {$link->getCategoryLink(params  here)}

Prestashop 1.7 : {url entity='category' id=(your product category id you can get from the $product object) id_lang=$id_lang}
Example : {url entity='category' id=$product.id_category_default id_lang=2}

There are additional configurations to this function that are explained further in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Using this code works fine:

```
<a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($category->id_category, $category->link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$product.category_name}</a>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).